# How to Connect SQL Server through HTML5, JS?

Tags: javascript, html

How We Can Connect SQL Server (Not WebSQL) using HTML5 and JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly. You will have to send requests to your server side technology, which will in turn execute SQL Server commands (and then return results back to your client).

Comment: Thanks for Reply... Where WebSQL (HTML5) DB is storing and How We can see the data in Database?

Comment: Open a new question for that (but search the site first if somebody has already asked that)